# Permissions issue while creating the file in linux

Tags: shell

Actually I am facing the issue while creating the file in particular directory. I have two environment and structure of both environment is same.

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 csaadm etl  24576 Apr 16 03:00 flag --------- env1
drwxr-xr-x  4 csaadm etl  24576 Apr 16 03:00 flag --------- env2
```

When one process create a file under this directory. file permission look like this. permission of file is not same.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 csaadm etl       0 Apr 16 01:00 schedule_5 --------- env1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 csaadm etl       0 Apr 16 04:00 schedule_6 --------- env2
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening and how to resolve this?

Comment: is it the same user..? *since you said there are 2 environments; different computer..?

Comment: second env is replica of first evn...

Comment: Is there any method that process creates any file with full permission without using chmod command

Comment: What's the output of `umask` in each environment?  If it's different, `man umask`.

Comment: umask value is same on both env...0000

Comment: ok..but question is that user is same and umask value is same so why files are creating with different permissions?

Comment: can we know how did you write it..?

Comment: if you have any code of it..?

Comment: file is created by informatica powercenter which is called by shell script

Answer (score 1):

Basically it would be better if you provide more information on what process and how the files are being created.

But so far you can go over following checks

1. Check the `umask` for the both environments
2. Check if the files are created within the same user context
3. Check the owner of the process which is creating the files.
4. etc

Need more help ? Then provide more information !

Comment: Actually...second env is replica of first evn and file is created by informatica powercenter which is called by shell script

Comment: Best to open a support case with informatica. Good luck.

Comment: Well, try to compare the replica user id on your replica envorment with the user id of your primary environment

Comment: Thanks Deimus...Can you please tell me how to compare the user id?